# Visual Studio 2012 slow compilation, high internet usage

Tags: performance, compilation, visual-studio-2012, download

When I compile my project in VS 2012, it takes forever (minute or 2). I have noticed, in my task manager, that the "System" is using internet connection heavily during the compilation.

I have tried disabling the symbols loading.

So far only thing that helped was me disabling my Local Area Connection.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I have also noticed that mine has increasingly gotten slower

Comment: It seems that the XAML designer is also very slow and is downloading something..

Comment: Th only quick fix I use for now is disabling and enabling my Local Area Connection which interrupts the download and allows the compilation to continue..

Comment: I had an async service that was running on my machine that was for some reason slowing down my compilations. Disabling or stopping it appears to have fixed it.

Comment: Did you check with wireshark (network trace) what is being downloaded?

Comment: What language are you compiling?

Comment: Which Edition of VS2012.
Also how many number of project are there in your solution and what's type of project are there in it.
Also what's your's operating system

Comment: Have you got an Entity Framework project/model in the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Could it be caused by extension or addin you have installed?
For example, NuGet will download missing packages during build if they're not there.

Try to monitor your network with application such as [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and it may point you in the right direction.

You may also run Visual Studio with /Log parameter and see if there is anything logged in the activity.log.

Finally, you can set build output to Diagnostic from Tools | Options | Project and Solutions | Build and Run and see if there's anything unusual there.

Comment: My project no longer takes any extra time to compile.. very strange. Maybe some update has fixed it. Also the build output is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This *may* have something to do with VS checking for revoked certificates. Have a look at this post...

[How to stop SSIS from "Phoning Home"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570200/how-to-stop-ssis-from-phoning-home)

I find it has significantly improved VS performance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have enabled the getting symbols from Microsoft servers. Go to visual studio options -> debugging -> Symbols and check your settings.

Comment: Since when are symbols downloaded at compile time?