# SSIS Script Editor loads very slow

Tags: ssis

In my role I use SSIS occasionally. In my lastest package I have used a Script Task. My machine is more than fast enough, runs 64 bit and has heaps of memory but whenever I try to edit a script I must wait nearly a minute for the code to load. I'm using VS 2012 and SQL 2012. Any ideas, continually going out of the Scriptmain.cs, especially to fix such finicky little problems is taking forever. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can it be that your virus scanner is being too busy scanning the VS files?

Comment: Perhaps you're seeing this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570200/how-to-stop-ssis-from-phoning-home

Comment: Faster to just edit with the text editor in VS. Sure you lose intellisense, but this thing is painfully slow to deal with. Not to mention we have to close the script window every time we make a change. Sheesh

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows control panel, "Internet Options" / "Advanced", under the "Security" group, uncheck "Check for publisher’s certificate revocation". Log off and log on again.

Comment: Even if this fixes the problem, it is [not recommended](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/964.certificate-revocation-list-crl-verification-an-application-choice.aspx) because it disables an important security feature

Comment: I've read a few things, including this one, which indicate the whole thing is a flawed idea, just turn it off: https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/04/19/revchecking.html

Comment: This fix made VS 2019 slower - way slower.

Comment: I did not see where the Certificate Revocation List had an effect on the overall time it takes to load the scripting task.   I found a location where it was listed on Connect.Microsoft.com but Microsoft scrapped that program.