# Editing SSIS Script Task/Component takes 15 sec. to open

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Since upgrading to SQL Server 2012, we have experienced that the editor for Script Task/Component takes around 15 seconds to open. After looking around online, I found some similar cases. But they seem to be related to SQL Server 2008, and the "hacks" no longer seems to have any effect in 2012.

Do you know of this issue and do you have a solution?

Here are some references describing the old issues:

[How to stop SSIS from "Phoning Home"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570200/how-to-stop-ssis-from-phoning-home/27359788)

[SSIS Script Editor loads very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540151/ssis-script-editor-loads-very-slow)

Also just found this issue submitted to MS:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789728/ssis-script-task-component-very-slow-to-open

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment then an answer but I don't have a high enough rep to leave a comment.

I have found this to be an issue in vs2013 as well. The only good work around for it that I have found is to set delay validation to true. This will prevent any potential connections to external sources from validating until runtime.

Comment: This is still an issue in Visual Studio 2015.  None of the workarounds increase loading time for me at all.  It takes about 10 seconds to load the Script Editor.  Why hasn't this been fixed???

Comment: Does VS2015 still use the 2012 shell for the editor?

Comment: I have the full version of VS 2015 installed so SSIS is using VS 2015 for the editor and the script language is Microsoft Visual C# 2015.

Comment: 15 seconds, you are lucky